# Submitting integer to shader without using uniforms?

Tags: opengl-es

I plan to eliminate all glUniform calls from my GLSL shaders in order to save costs in state switching. For that purpose, I plan to use an UBO that is bound to the shader permanently. Different draw calls use different parts of the UBO (it's basically an array). In order to tell the draw call which entry to use, I have to submit an integer to the vertex/fragment shaders. The problem is, that on the system I have to use even casting a single glUniform call will cause an expensive state update, so I cannot use glUniform at all.

Do you know a solution that will work on GLES 3.1 and one that will work on GLES 2?

GLES doesn't have glMulti* calls yet and base vertex only from 3.2 upwards as far as I know. And adding another vertex attribute may be costly.

Comment: Sounds like a case of solving the wrong problem to me. Uniforms should be cheap, that's the point of them. A framework which makes a single uniform unusably expensive is badly broken - solve that problem rather than working around it. You're going to need uniforms at some point.

Comment: As I stated, the graphics driver I have to use has has a fixed overhead that occurs if I update even one uniform before a draw call. The only way to circumvent this according to the manufacturer is not to call glUniform at all and use UBOs instead.

Comment: Uniform buffer objects don't even exist on GLES 2 I thought.

Comment: I know. I have to develop for 3.1 with an option for 2. Thus, I first try to solve the index problem, then the replace-UBO problem.

Comment: "As I stated ..." well you stated that state switching was expensive, not that the problem was in the graphics driver. The problem could have e.g. been in the game engine.

Comment: The only solution I can think of will just get a different kind of state switching (e.g. swapping a UBO per draw which contains the index into the second main UBO). If uniform switching is expensive, I don't see why UBO switching is going to be any less expensive.

Comment: Curiosity - how many draw calls do you have per frame? Is the "expense" simply that you have too many draw calls rather than the cost per draw being too high? Mobile platforms tend to have quite limited draw call budgets.

Comment: About 700 drawcalls per frame.

Comment: "And adding another vertex attribute **may** be costly" - You just admitted not having measured :-) If it is a single integer then chances are you can fold it into whatever other attributes you send. Since GLES 2.0 GLSL does not have true integer support anyway you might just get away with putting it in the w coordinate. Try it, measure, get back here and tell us what you've learned.